# Valor Diferente - Consulta Oracle

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Na consulta abaixo na coluna `Valor_Total_da_Ordem` está dando um valor totalmente diferente, muito acima do que de fato era para ser. O valor está dando 55990,62. Sendo que o valor correto é para ser 1333,11.

O que pode ter ocorrido?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.nm_fantasia_estab Unidade,
    m.nr_ordem_compra Número_Ordem_Compra,
    l.cd_cgc CNPJ_Fornecedor,
    l.ds_razao_social Razão_Social_Fornecedor,
    sum(v.vl_vencimento) Valor_Total_da_Ordem,
    substr(
        tasy.obter_nome_pf (p.cd_pessoa_fisica),
        1,
        255
    ) Aprovador,
    trunc (m.dt_aprovacao) Data_Aprovacao
FROM
    TASY.PROCESSO_APROV_COMPRA p,
    tasy.PROCESSO_COMPRA c,
    TASY.ORDEM_COMPRA_ITEM t,
    tasy.ORDEM_COMPRA m,
    TASY.ESTABELECIMENTO e,
    TASY.pessoa_juridica l,
    TASY.ORDEM_COMPRA_VENC v
WHERE
    p.NR_SEQUENCIA = c.NR_SEQUENCIA
AND t.NR_ORDEM_COMPRA = m.NR_ORDEM_COMPRA
AND e.cd_estabelecimento = m.cd_estabelecimento
AND l.cd_cgc = m.cd_cgc_fornecedor
AND v.nr_ordem_compra = m.nr_ordem_compra
AND m.nr_ordem_compra = 29020
AND p.nr_sequencia IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        nr_seq_aprovacao
    FROM
        tasy.ordem_compra_item
    WHERE
        nr_ordem_compra = 29020
)
GROUP BY
    e.nm_fantasia_estab,
    m.nr_ordem_compra,
    c.nr_sequencia,
    l.cd_cgc,
    l.ds_razao_social,
    trunc (m.dt_aprovacao),
    m.dt_aprovacao,
    substr(
        tasy.obter_nome_pf (p.cd_pessoa_fisica),
        1,
        255
    )
ORDER BY
    m.nr_ordem_compra DESC;
```

Comment: Não está repetindo os valores? Tenta adicionar um DISTINCT e rodar novamente seu select.

Comment: Apenas com o select não da pra lhe dizer os valores que devem ser retornados ou não, porém, existe um CROSS JOIN em sua consulta que possívelmente está retornando mais registros do que deveria e estourando o valor total.

Comment: @Laerte, fiz isso... mas ele da um valor menor. Pois na tabela ele tem 3 valores.
444,34
444,34
444,43

E assim, usando o distinct ele retira o 444,34.

Comment: Me parece estar faltando um join entre alguma tabela, você tem 7 tabelas no from e apenas 5 joins no where. Dá uma conferida nos teus joins

Comment: Você relaciona P=C mas não relaciona nenhuma dessas duas tabelas com outras do teu from, sem conhecer a modelagem do teu banco fica difícil identificar qual JOIN está faltando.

Comment: ôpa @PabloTondolodeVargas, deu certo. Ajustei aqui os joins. Obrigado

Comment: @renanbessa, já que resolveu o seu problema, por favor responda você mesmo a sua pergunta explicando como resolveu, talvez sirva para ajudar outro usuário passando pelo mesmo problema.